# My query returns null result if the field contains a special character

Tags: php, sql-server

I made a simple query in SQL Server with PHP

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Art WHERE Articulo = 'NAME';
```

And one of the fields I need to read returns `NULL` if the data contains any spanish character. I could work with random characters, but not with this null values. What could be causing them?

The `collation` of the DB is `modern_spanish`

Comment: When you say *one of the fields I need to read* do you mean a row you need to *return*? Usually it wouldn't return `NULL`, but instead something like `????`. What's the datatype of the field? I'm guessing `VARCHAR` as opposed to `NVARCHAR`

Comment: the field is a varchar and returns NULL. If I make the query in sql server management studio I get something like "EDREDÓN CON PLUMAS", but when I try the same query with PHP if gives me FALSE or NULL.I could accept an "EDRED?N CON PLUMAS" answer, but the NULL is really causing me problems

Answer (score 1):

Use this line at top of the page with db connection object.

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

Comment: Do you think this would work? I was working on Microsoft SQL Server. I no longer have access to that project so I can't test it.

Comment: Sorry! @AllfaridMoralesGarcía this line of code is used for MySql Server.